# Use literals strings with ICU

Tags: c++, unicode, literals, icu

I'm wondering if there's a way to use literal strings with ICU, I currently use wide character literal string like this:

```
u_strcpy( catColor, L"Yellow0" );

if (u_strcmp( catcolor, L"Yellow0" ) != 0)
    CatColorIsYellow();
```

I've heard about UNICODE_STRING but the result looks the same than with L""

Comment: what about UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear what you're asking about, but it appears you mean declaring them? In that case, see the [UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/unistr_8h.html#a6cd56429cbf4fe567a97c9d1a46e96ae) macro:

```
const UnicodeString someString = UNICODE_STRING_SIMPLE("Some String");
```

If you're looking to declare C style Unicode string literal, take a look at the [U_STRING_DECL](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#adf24e553d2f30e3bde48ff98d9b0e6bc) and [U_STRING_INIT](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html#af0dccce2caf6c8c657b65112f393a75b) macros.

See also: [C++ Unicode String Literals](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings#TOC-C-Unicode-String-Literals)